# .htaccess Rewrite Rules "/" issue

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have an issue with my .htacess Rewrite Rules...

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/(.+)$ /index.php?pg=$1&cmd=$2
```

It work, but if I write in the ULR `mydomine.com/somthing/something-else/`
The resulting `$cmd` is `something-else/` how to remove the final slash?

P.S. If I write in the URL `mydomine.com/somthing/something-else` it work, but I like to give it more flexibility...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?pg=$1&cmd=$2
```

Comment: Now a new problem appeared: the link to the CSS in the page (/css/stlye.css) is passed from the rules... I have putted the [PT,QSA] at the end of the rule. What else?

Comment: @Alberto:  I added a rewrite condition so that the rule is ignore if the URL is a file on the server.